# Community detection and comparison in igraph

Tags: python, igraph

I am using the `multilevel` algorithm in `igraph` to detect communities among the same set of the nodes *over a period of time* (i.e. multiple and potentially different clusterings will be produced for the same set of nodes). I have two questions regarding the output of the detection algorithm (which may also apply to other detection algorithms in `igraph`):

1. How does the algorithm decide the membership assignment? In other words, is there any rule or pattern that decides which nodes are assigned to the 1st subgraph of the resulted `VertexClustering` object and which ones will be assigned to the 2nd subgraph, and so on?
2. If there is some consistent membership assignment pattern, is there a method to compare the membership of two communities that are detected at different times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. See the paper referenced in the documentation: http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/python/igraph.Graph-class.html#community_multilevel
2. See http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/python/igraph.clustering-module.html#compare_communities

Comment: thank you for the suggestions. Regarding #1, I guess an example will clarify my actual use case: if nodes `1, 2 and 3` are grouped into a cluster indexed as the first community returned by a `VertexClustering` object, then will a cluster containing these nodes be returned as the first community in a clustering object if I call the method again on the same set of nodes later? (of course, the graph structure may change but I assume here nodes `1, 2 and 3` still end up in the same cluster).

Comment: @skyork: no, it is not guaranteed; the numbers are quite arbitrary depending on how the algorithm decides to merge communities (and it may even happen that the maximum modularity occurs at a completely different "resolution level" even if you added or removed only a few nodes or edges). But none of the methods in `compare_communities` are sensitive to the exact numbering.

Comment: If you want to keep the numbering sort-of-consistent, you will need to take two consecutive clusterings, calculate their confusion matrix (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix), and then use a simple greedy algorithm to find an appropriate assignment between the groups of the two clusterings. (Basically you try to select the largest values from the confusion matrix to get an assignment). This is trickier than it seems because clusters may have been merged or split between time instances.

Comment: An alternative is to order the clusters by size in both clusterings and then assign the largest cluster in clustering 1 to the largest cluster in clustering 2 etc.